# Is it possible to distinguish several Firefox browsing windows?

Tags: firefox, awesome-wm, urxvt

I use AwesomeWM, and would like to place different Firefox windows on differents tags. For instance, I would like to group a few tabs in a window for "communication websites"  (Slack, Whatsapp, Mattermost, Hangouts, …), and it would stay on a "messenging" tag. Meanwhile, I would like my regular firefox browsing session to remain on a "web" tag.

My current rc.lua has the following line:

```
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" }, properties = { screen = 1, tag = "web" } },
```

which does not enable to distinguish several browsing sessions by their name. Most terminal emulators seem to implement a `-name` option, which makes the match by awesome rules rather easy:

```
 { rule = { instance = "rootterm" },properties = { screen = 1, tag = "root", switchtotag = true } },
```

Does anyone know if Firefox may be used for such a use case, and how?

If not, I may be interested by any solution involving another browser (like Chromium, Opera). I would however prefer not to have a solution like "Opera for communication and Firefox for regular browsing".